# Hive not running with derby

Tags: hadoop, configuration, hive, derby

I'm running hive but i'm getting error

```
Caused by: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Unable to open a test connection to the given database. JDBC url = jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true, username = APP. Terminating connection pool (set lazyInit to true if you expect to start your database after your app). Original Exception: ------
java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database 'metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
```

Here

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Failed to create database '/home/Desktop/metastore/metastore_db', see the next exception for details.
```

hadoop running fine and my installation directory for
Hadoop - opt/hadoop
Hive - opt/hadoop
Derby - opt/derby

Hive configuration file - hive-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jdbc:derby:metastore_db;create=true</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
<value>org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: When it says "See the next exception for details", do this: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Comment: Go through this link.  http://sumajbigdata.blogspot.in/search?q=hive+installation . It is helpful.

Comment: Thanks I'm newbie to hadoop